# Element ID as variable in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code which suppose to take an effect on an element with passed ID name to the function

```
function updateElements(tab_name) {
    var tab_name = tab_name;

    // ...

    $("#table-responsive-" + tab_name).load(url, function(resp, status, xhr, tab_name) {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip-pass"]').tooltip({ 'placement': 'bottom' });
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ 'placement': 'top'});
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            trigger: 'hover',
            'placement': 'top', 
            'container': 'body'
        });

        $('#' + tab_name).DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "columnDefs": [{ 
                "orderable": false, 
                "targets": 4 
            }]
        });
    });
}
```

`"#table-responsive-" + tab_name` works fine but `$('#' + tab_name).DataTable()` doesn't. Any clue what I have missed?

Comment: $('#'+tab_name).DataTable() uses the variable from the function... which propably is null

Comment: There's no reason to do `var tab_name = tab_name;`. Parameter variables are automatically local variables, you don't have to declare them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the callback function for `$.load()` isn't passed 4 parameters, it's passed just 3.  Your fourth parameter inside the 'complete' function thus becomes `undefined` - and since you've shadowed the original `tab_name` with this function parameter, the selector won't work:

```
$("#table-responsive-"+tab_name).load(url, function(resp, status, xhr, tab_name) {
//tab_name was never passed in, remove it from args list
});
```

this is [the signature](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for the 'complete' function from the documentation for the `$.load():`:

> complete 
>   Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR
>   jqXHR ) A callback function that is executed when the request
>   completes.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `tab_name` as a global variable as well as an argument to the load function. So it seems as if the argument is replacing the value of the global `tab_name` variable. That's all I could find out. Try replacing the argument name.

Comment: Just take out the `tab_name` argument to the callback function. It only gets 3 arguments.